# What is the best way to use context-param in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

In my web.xml I set context param "pathToImages". In my jsp files to get path to my images files I use EL, like this:

```
<img src="${initParam.pathToImages}"/image.jpg" />
```

But I have problem with JavaScript. In my js files I have code:

> setInnerHTML("somePlace", "<.img src='images/s.gif'>");

I know this isn't beautiful code but it isn't mine :) I cannot get my pathToImages in the same way like from jsp. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it as parameter to the js function: `function createImage(path) {..}` and invoke it with `createImage('${initParam.pathToImages}')`

Another, perhaps a better option is to have a js variable and initialize it with the desired value. In the JS file:

```
var imagePath;

function init(config) {
    imagePath = config.imagePath;
}
```

and in your header:

```
init({imagePath: '${initparam.pathToImages}'});
```

Comment: thanks for idea but I have many functions with such code, so this will be big refactor. Secondly some functions has many arguments at the moment, adding next argument will be ugly

Comment: @smas - ok, see my next suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you are using templates to build your pages (i.e., tiles or velocity templates) you could assign the variable in your base template with a scriptlet, like:

```
<script> var imagePath = '<%= config.getServletContext().getInitParameter("pathToImages") %>'; </script>
```

Then you can refer to the imagePath variable in your js files.

Not pretty, but I don't believe there is a way to access the servlet context from a javascript file directly.